# Objective C: async block structure VS async network request + completion block

Tags: ios, asynchronous, block, afnetworking-2

I have been using the following structure in my projects for consuming API data:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // SYNCHRONOUS network request
    // Data processing
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // UI update
    });
});
```

On the other hand, I have seen quite frequently another structure where the network request is asynchronous (i.e. using AFNetworking) and then the **data processing** and **UI update** are handled in the completion block (which is not async - I think).
Here is an example of what I am saying:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  // Data processing
  // UI update
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  // Error handling
}];

[operation start];
```

So, my questions are:

1. In the second structure there the **data processing** is not being run asynchronously, it is?
2. Why are we generally encouraged to run async network requests instead of sync ones from async blocks/threads.
3. Why the second structure is much more known and spread than the first?

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Sync requests will freeze your UI until it is completed. In short your program waits till the request is completed. Async request wont freeze  your UI as the request will be made and you program can perform other tasks.

Comment: @RohanBhale The OP knows that; that wasn't what he asked.

Comment: @rohan, that's why the sync request is called on a background queue, so it doesn't freeze the UI at all.

Comment: The second structure with AFHTTPRequestOperation is also async. It is preferred because the syntax is much easier to understand and the code  is cleaner.

Comment: @RohanBhale In the second structure the data processing is not async, it is being run in the main queue, there is my concern...

Comment: If your concern is that the processing is taking up the main thread you can call GCD from within the return block where you can do like in your first code example but only do the processing there.

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperation does default to running its completion block in the main queue. But you can set the successCallbackQueue property to have it run on a background thread. If you do that, you'll need to dispatch your UI update to the main queue like you do in your first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion async calls are much more elegant solutions for networking in any language.

1. Yes data processing is done in main thread in that example. Parsing strings and creating objects in UI isn't really a cpu cycle consuming job. However lets say you download an image and you want to process it, you shouldn't do it in this block (maybe spawn another thread). But image processing is another scope.it isn't related to the network code so network code is working as intended.
2. With async network calls, you can cancel/pause the request. But in sync network calls you cannot do that.
3. First of all gcd is new to the objective-c (i am not really sure but it was available after iOS 4. correct me if i am wrong). Before that we were using delegation and it was a lot of boilerplate codes. But with the second approach you can easily manage the networking code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So then, if the data requires of heavy processing, in the completion block of the second structure we would have to repeat the dispatch_async schema? Does not seem like the way to go :S

Comment: I thing it depends on the heavy processing. I mean I never saw an app that does matrix calculation in a response from server. Also processing data is out of scope of network calls.

Answer (score 0):

> In the second structure there the data processing is not being run
>   asynchronously, it is?

No its not. Its run on the main thread. But the time consuming task of fetching data from remote server is already done on another thread. Once the data is retrieved, data processing will not take much time generally and can be run on the main thread. In rare cases(i have not come across any such) if data processing itself takes time and appears to block UI, then we can use NSOperations or GCD queues to process them.

This is achieved by making use of blocks which is just like a callback function.

> Why the second structure is much more known and spread than the first?

Its easier to implement and also to understand once you know the syntax for blocks ;)

Comment: So, in theory, if the amount of data is very large and the processing is heavy-cpu-consuming (maybe some special parsing or dynamic generation of images with the data obtained), the second structure could lead to the UI lags and freezes? Let's then just use the first and make it a standard :-)

Comment: The completion block indeed executes *asynchronously* with respect to the call site. Whether a task executes *asynchronously* or *synchronously* requires a relation to the call-site: if the effect of the function is immediately visible to the call-site after its invocation returned, then the function is "synchronous". If the effect is only visibly at some time later after it's invocation returned, then the function is *asynchronous*. Where the function actually executes doesn't matter - it can be any thread.